# google map intent - having own position and json data markers

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps

i am beginner in coding. Hope that anyone can help me. How should i using the user coordinates that i have detected and the marker coordinates to show the route by using google map intent? Most tutorial that i find out key in either the coordinates inside or by keying the address. I want to add a button that will show the function.

```
  var markers_data = [{
                "id":"7",
                "place":"Cafeteria 2",
                "nearTo":"Front door of Caferia 2",
                "lat":"2.31065941",
                "lng":"102.31864929",
                "type":"oil"},

                {"id":"8",
                 "place":"Cafeteria 1",
                 "nearTo":"Back door of Caferia 1",
                 "lat":"2.31391430",
                 "lng":"102.31797791",
                 "type":"oil"}];

var geocoder;
var map;

function initialize() {
//Google map option
if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (p) {
                var LatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(p.coords.latitude, p.coords.longitude);
                var mapOptions = {
                    center: LatLng, // map center
        zoom: 10, //zoom level, 0 = earth view to higher value
        panControl: true, //enable pan Control
        zoomControl: true, //enable zoom control
        zoomControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL //zoom control size
    },
        scaleControl: true, // enable scale control
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP // google map type
    };
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: LatLng,
                    map: map,
                    icon: 'images/user-marker.png',
                     content:"<b>You're here! Your location:</b><br />Latitude: " + p.coords.latitude + "<br />Longitude: " + p.coords.longitude
                });
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                    infoWindow.setContent(marker.content);
                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                });    
            });

        } else {
            alert('Geo Location feature is not supported in this browser.');
        }
  update(markers_data)
}

         var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
function update(markers) {
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(),
marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    var place = markers[i].place;
    var nearTo = markers[i].nearTo;
    var lat = markers[i].lat;
    var lng = markers[i].lng;
    var type = markers[i].type;
    var html = "<b>Details:</b><br />Latitude: " + lat + "<br />Longitude: " + lng + "<br />Building: " + place + "<br />Near To: " + nearTo + "<br />Type: " + type + "<br />Route:" + "<input type='button' onClick=getDir() value='Go!'>" + "<br />Website: " + "<a href='http://www.go-green.netai.net/web/'>More details</a>" + "<br />Video: " + "<a href='http://www.youtube.com/embed?listType=search&list=go-green'>More videos about go green</a>"


    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    bounds.extend(latlng);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, place, nearTo, lat, lng, type,html) {

                return function() {
                    infowindow.setContent(html);
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                }
            })(marker, place, nearTo, lat, lng, type,html));
 map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
}

 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need the current location. To launch a Google Maps navigation via intent, simply call `google.navigation:q=your+marker+location` intent.

Look at [this page for example](https://jsfiddle.net/psuouvmw/1/embedded/result/).

Comment: the function that i wish to add is when user click on any marker they can get the route from user current location to the specific marker that has been clicked through google map intent.

Comment: If I am understanding it correctly, you want to launch an intent that launch google maps for routing, right? Or do you want to display the route in your application without using intent?

Comment: ya i want to launch an intent that launch google map for routing~ my application will show a google map with user current location and some others markers. An info window will be open when press the marker, i wanna to add a button function in the info window that will show the intent google map routing (from user's position to the marker that i pressed).